# How to create a completely new PDF file if there is NO existing file?

Tags: java, file, pdf, itext

I am using the iText library to create a PDF file in java. The only problem is: I have to create first a PDF file manually, then take its path and put it like this:

```
private final static String FILE = "C:\\Projekt\\lul.pdf";
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
```

My question is: How can I use the iText library without having to create a PDF file manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private final static String FILE = "C:\\Projekt\\lul.pdf";
File yourFile = new File(FILE);
yourFile.createNewFile(); // if file already exists will do nothing 
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(yourFile));
```

Answer (score 2):

> iText is an open source API and it does let you do that as well.

1. Add below dependency to pom.xml :

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Java Class:

   ```
     Document document = new Document();
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new 
     FileOutputStream(Example.pdf;));
     document.open();
     document.add(new Paragraph(Welcome To StackOverflow;));
     document.close();
     writer.close();
   ```